# Double tap Touch event in Custom View does not return proper coordinates when Talk Back is ON

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm trying to make my application more accessible trough Talk back feature in android. Talk back works properly except when I double tap on Custom view, touch event always return same coordinates x: 336 , y: 519 . I have tried both `event.getRawX()`, it returns x: 360 all the time when I do double tap. But interestingly if I tap with two fingers it returns proper value.

Is there any solution or hack to get proper coordinates on double tap touch event on Custom View when Talk Back is ON???

This is the sample code.

```
public class CustomView extends TextView {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.setContentDescription("x:" + event.getX() + ", y:" + event.getY());
        setText("x : " + event.getX() + " , y : " + event.getY() + "\n" + "Raw x: " + event.getRawX() + ", y : "
                + event.getRawY() + "\n ");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also catch this issue, can anyone know the solution. Thank so much!